# Storing ASP.Net MVC Views in the Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, ironruby

For an ASP.Net MVC application, I'm interested in storing some views and/or partial views in the database so that a few semi-technical users can do some basic view logic. Does anyone have any tips or lessons from experience on doing this?

I know [Phil Haack wrote a blog post on this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/22/scripted-db-views.aspx) about a year ago. He used IronRuby for scripting his views, (which would be fine for me). He created a quick proof-of-concept, but I can't find any other information on the topic.

Any ideas, thoughts, tips, etc would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember to RESTART IIS Express after each change or tweak because it caches the locations, files and apparently results even though I set it not too, and all that. I was banging my head and then realised after restarting IIS that it all worked without existing file name, without it being an embedded resource, as long as it had '.cshtml' and made sure I overrode the directory bit too. THanks you helped me partially create my solutions. Phew!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Here you go](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views). All that you need is to write a custom [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) and register it within the ASP.NET hosting environment. Works also with classic WebForms.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Link is broken can you share it again ?

Comment: http://blog.rebuildall.net/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views