# How can I get .cshtml from Database dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I have to say: This is a different question from these:

- http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/
- [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controlle)
- http://blog.rocketbase.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-virtual-path-provider/
- [ASP.NET MVC load Razor view from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218454/asp-net-mvc-load-razor-view-from-database)

I want to provide dynamic .cshtml Content from db when i want.

Example:

City Table,FreeHtml Column

```
@model City 
@Html.CheckBox - @Model.Name - @Html.CustomHelper
```

How can I write as html helper:

```
@model City
@Html.RazorRaw(Model.FreeHtml,Model)
```

or as CustomViewResult

```
public RazorPartialViewResult CityHtml(City city)
{
   return new RazorPartialViewResult(city.FreeHtml,city)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here:
[Storing ASP.Net MVC Views in the Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457164/storing-asp-net-mvc-views-in-the-database)

You need to replace the default view engine(s) with a custom one.
Here is an example:
http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx