# References to building dynamic online forms in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms, razor

I would need to create dynamic online forms, e.g. using ASP.NET MVC and Razor as view engine. So you would be able to select a form template, populate it, add new fields, etc.

Are there any references/guides I could follow? I tried searching but couldn't really find any. Creating a main template view with controller, and partial pages with sub-controllers could be one way. This way validation and transformations would be quite well encapsulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question here on StackOverflow: 
[Dynamically Produce Razor Views at Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703119/dynamically-produce-razor-views-at-runtime)

Also, among the ten tricks for razor views, the two last tips are about building views and eegerly generating code from razor: 
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/09/ten-tricks-for-razor-views.aspx

Maybe those two links can help you getting started at the least