# how to render layout as string in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have my entire Layout as a string in my database and I want to render the layout from database to my View.
for example:

```
 public ActionResult index()
 {
   string layout = GetLayout();

   //in below how should I render layout to view 
   return View("index", layout);
 }
```

I already use `result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, key.ToString());` to render layout but it avoids to render HTML Helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using below code and it is working fine for me.i am also using it in Web API for returning View in form of string.

For more you can create **Static Class** and make below method static.

```
 public string RenderPartialView(string controllerName, string viewName, object model = null) {
     System.Web.HttpContextBase contextBase = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);

     var routeData = new RouteData();
     routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
     var controllerContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(contextBase, routeData,
      new EmptyController());

     var razorViewEngine = new System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine();
     var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName, false);

     var writer = new StringWriter();
     System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext;


     viewContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext(controllerContext, razorViewResult.View,
      new System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary(model), new System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary(), writer);

     viewContext.ViewData["controller"] = controllerName;

     HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("controller", controllerName);

     razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

     string htmlString = writer.ToString();
     writer.Dispose();

     return htmlString;
    }
```

---

```
private class EmptyController: System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase {
  protected override void ExecuteCore() {}
 }
```

Now please find example how we can call it from controller.

```
RenderPartialView("Home", string.Format("~/Views/Home/{0}.cshtml", "Index"));
```

I hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: I want the only layout to render in the controller but this render the view with controller. I read [https://wouterdekort.com/2012/10/12/rendering-an-asp-net-mvc-view-to-a-string-in-a-web-api-controller/] .

Comment: Can I use the layout controller that string in the database?

Comment: what change in the source ? @Ankit

Comment: `     var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName, false);
` how change for layout? @Ankit

Comment: you can pass empty controller in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is no inbuilt mechanism to achieve that one.Needs to have a custom solution for that one.This topic has already been discussed in this post.
[Dynamically Produce Razor Views at Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703119/dynamically-produce-razor-views-at-runtime) you can refer that one.