# Using ViewComponents in RTE

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am trying to use ViewComponents tag helpers in CKEditor to show some products but it doesn't.

I created a vc tag helper like this :

```
<vc:products html-class="col-12 col-md-5" html-style="" skip="0" take="10"></vc:products>
```

Now I am trying to use this code in CKEditor, I mean post editors can call products anywhere they want. but it doesn't work. CKEditor shows it as a html code.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This code will be actually executed on the server side and it will add partial html to your page then the server will return it to the client.

`<vc:products html-class="col-12 col-md-5" html-style="" skip="0" take="10"></vc:products>`

Here I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you cannot dynamically use tag helpers on the client side. May be this link can help you.

[Dynamically Produce Razor Views at Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703119/dynamically-produce-razor-views-at-runtime)